# How to create vertices on the fly based on the labels of edges in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to solve LTS(Labelled Transition System) using OCaml.
I have edges with labels on them and source of the edges. Now I want to create the destination of the edge whose name depends on the source and label of the edge.

I not very fluent with OCaml, so please elaborate your answers.

Comment: I think you need to give more detail on what you're trying to do. In OCaml you usually want to start by deciding what types you're going to use. If you show your types, and the type of the function you want to implement, it will be a lot easier to help. (Or maybe you'll figure it out yourself while thinking about the types--this is what usually happens for me :-)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield My vertices are of the type of list which contains the tuples of char. My labels on the edges is of the type char*char*int. Based on the labels of edge between them and the source vertex, i want to create a new vertex

Comment: Sorry, this isn't very clear. You say "tuple"--do you mean a pair (a 2-tuple)? Are you saying that each vertex has a list pairs of characters? Or maybe you have a list of vertices each of which has a pair of characters? You could expand your question with your types coded in OCaml, which makes them completely explicit. Also give the type of the function you want to write. If you just want to know how to create things on the fly in general, the answer is that you write a function whose input is a collection and whose output is a larger collection.